# IFrame Height in Script Editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, iframe

I have a iframe placed into a script editor.

When the height of the iframe is set to 100% the images all size correctly but the script editor web part does not.

[image: IFrame Height]

How can I get the editor to mach the size of the content inside it?

EDIT: This will resize the iframe to take half of the window size on load. A few tweaks are needed to correct it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function resize_iframe()
        {
            var height=window.innerWidth;//Firefox
            if (document.body.clientHeight)
            {
                height=document.body.clientHeight;//IE
            }
            //Resize the iframe according to the size of the
            //window (all these should be on the same line)
            document.getElementById("iframe").style.height=parseInt(height-document.getElementById("iframe").offsetTop-8)/2+"px";
        }
        // This will resize the iframe every
        // time you change the size of the window.
        window.onresize=resize_iframe; 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following javascript code to your master page. It let you manually resize the web parts in edit mode:

```
$(function() {
    $('div[id^='WebPartWPQ']').resizable({ 
        handles: 'all', 
        autoHide: true
        })
        .find('iframe').height('100%');
});
```

See [this article](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2009/01/05/jquery-for-everyone-manually-resizing-web-parts-aspx/) for more information

Comment: I have tried adding this but will need to find the correct ID as I cant see 'WebPartWPQ' in the HTML.

Comment: @JamesMichaelLucas I tried this on our own Sharepoint. In edit mode the correct id is: WebPartTitleWPQ7